# Conditional awk across 4 columns

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have a tab-delimited file with 9 columns as follows:

```
1   25555818    T   14  0   0   0   14  0:0:0:14
2   25555819    T   14  7   0   0   7   7:0:0:7
3   25555820    G   13  0   0   13  0   0:0:13:0
4   25555821    A   0   0   0   0   0   0:0:0:0
5   25555822    G   11  0   0   11  0   0:0:0:0
6   25555823    T   11  2   0   0   9   2:0:0:9
7   25555824    T   11  0   0   0   11  0:0:0:11
8   25555825    G   11  5   0   3   3   5:0:3:3
```

I'd like to keep only rows where there are at least two values over zero in either of columns 5,6,7,8. So in the example above, the rows I want to keep are rows 2,6,8. In other words, if there are at least 3 zeroes in column 5-8, the row should be discarded.

The catch is that column 9 is the product of merging columns 5-8, so it may be used for the the pattern match as well; however, as with before, the pattern is not necessarily 3 consecutive zeroes. There just has to be at least 3 zeroes out of the 4 values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="\t"} (($5!=0)+($6!=0)+($7!=0)+($8!=0))>=2'
```

And a terser variant for the C hackers:

```
awk -F $'\t' '(!!$5+!!$6+!!$7+!!$8)>=2'
```